# Upgrading from GVM to SDKMAN

Tags: gvm, sdkman

I just upgraded from GVM to SDKMAN. When I run any of the list commands to see what versions of the various sdks I have installed (e.g. `sdk list grails`), none of them are getting displayed with asterisks next to them even though they were installed and being used through GVM. Not sure what the deal is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cause might be you didn't run the following command

```
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

For more detail, I wrote the post on updating sdkman from gvm.

http://mike-neck.hatenadiary.com/entry/2015/09/17/234228

Comment: **WARNING**: Don't blindly copy and paste the example above as it uses a directory **/path/to/home** to and not ~ as you would expect

Answer (score 1):

They're in e.g. `~/.sdkman/grails` now, not e.g. `~/.grails`. Moving them should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I found a symlink that points to the latest version in:

~/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current

I'm using SDKMAN 4.0.37